# pandas dataframe : creating pivot_table on a data frame without giving values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a text file with data in the following format

```
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^paus
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^german
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^photo
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^polish
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^find
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^extra
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^access
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^privat
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^locat
101.223.129.4 918801641445^0^thank
```

I have read this in pandas using following code:

```
cols = ['msisdn','prob','desc']
txt_file = pd.read_csv('app_desc_fltrd.txt',sep="^",header=0,names=cols,low_memory=False)
```

Now I want to create a pivot table on this data using

```
pivot_tbl = pd.pivot_table(data,index=['msisdn','prob'],columns=['desc'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transpose_txt_file.py", line 22, in <module>
    create_pivot(txt_file,cols)
  File "transpose_txt_file.py", line 15, in create_pivot
    pivot_tbl = pd.pivot_table(data,index=['msisdn','prob'],columns=['desc'])
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/pivot.py", line 115, in pivot_table
    agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 676, in agg
    return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2615, in aggregate
    return getattr(self, arg)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 691, in mean
    return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2535, in _cython_agg_general
    new_items, new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(how, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "/opt/anaconda2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2585, in _cython_agg_blocks
    raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I am able to successfully create the pivot table with a little change.

```
pivot_tbl = pd.pivot_table(txt_file ,index=['msisdn'],columns=['desc'],values='desc')
```

But in this case I am losing my mapping of msisdn and prob field.

Any suggestion on **how could i create pivot table having ['msisdn','prob'] in rows, ['desc'] in columns and an indicator variable for presence of desc in values filed** would be much appreciated.

Basically for a given msisdn, prob will never change. Just if this could help in any way.

Thanks.

Comment: what is `data`? it's not the dataframe `txt_file`?

Comment: didn't get what are you asking actually. But to my understanding, yes txt_file is the data frame created and raw data was stored in file app_desc_fltrd.txt.

Comment: I mean in `pd.pivot_table(data,index=['msisdn'],columns=['desc'],value='desc')`, what is `data` ??

Comment: Can you provide desired output? How do you want data presented? Pandas provide various solutions: [transpose()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), [groupby()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [stack(), wide_to_long(), melt(), pivot()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) in addition to [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to proceed this way with `pivot_table` - you got some typos in your code:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.pivot_table(txt_file, rows=['msisdn','prob'], cols='desc',aggfunc=len)
```

You can also use `groupby`:

```
txt_file.groupby(['prob','msisdn'])['desc'].value_counts().unstack()
```